# Large text files load not working on android

Tags: android, arraylist, text-files, bufferedreader, assets

Here is the code of function:

```
public void loadTextFile(String textFileName, ArrayList<String> dictionary) 
{
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); //files manager
//reader = public bufferedReader
//word = public String
//dictionary = public ArrayList<String>

//load file to buffer
try {
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open(textFileName)));
} catch (IOException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
word = " "; 
//loop, save words from buffer to dictionary
while(word != null)
{
try {
  word = reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  word = null;
}
if (word != null) {
  dictionary.add(word);
}
}//end while
//buffer close
try {
reader.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}

} //end function
```

If I try load small file <1MB, It works fine and rather fast.
If the files(partialy) are more than 1MB, but less than about 3MB, it works slow (4-6min).
If the files are bigger, it's not working, and I have information in emulator:
"The application app (process processing.test.app) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". I don't know what is wrong.
I try: pre-allocated ArrayList, load file to few ArrayList's, but still not working.
I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is unresolved

Comment: First, that does not excuse you creating a duplicate question. Second, when you used Traceview to determine where you are spending your time (as I suggested in a comment on your original question), what did you learn?

Answer (score 0):

First off, word can become null somewhere along the file and the loop will exit (since you explicitly set word to null on an exception). Do you get a stack trace?

1. Try to move the code to a background process using AsyncTask [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
2. Execute on real device if you have one

Comment: word = reader.readLine(); is stopped in the middle of the file. I don't know what can I get a stack trace, I'm new in android. It is posible that the memory is too small on emulator or device? I execute app on real device, and it does not start. I was thinking about AsyncTask, it can be really helpful?

Comment: This was a while ago but 
1) check logcat for error messages when you connect phone and start app via eclipse and 
2) you can set memory size in emulator.